# Touchesbegan not detecting what is being touched

Tags: iphone, ios, touch, imageview, touchesbegan

I'm building a rotating banner using a NSTimer to keep track of the current image with the image being animated from 5 different images. I have a touchesBegan set up to keep handle the touch event on the banner if someone clicks it. My proof-of-concept works, but moving it into another project, it breaks.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([touch view] == myImageView){
    [self getImage];
    NSLog(@"%@", currentImage);
}
}
```

Now when I put break points into my project, it grabs the touch just fine, but when it gets to the
     if ([touch view] == myImageView) 
it doesn't detect that the image view is being touched.

Comment: I have rebuilt it and got it to work using this, I forgot myImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES; however in our main project, this isn't working so well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what would cause that but have you tried using a UIGestureRecognizer? Try something like the code below and see if the method gets called.

```
  //Add Gesture Recognizer
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(imageSelected)];
  tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  [theImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

  //Memory Cleanup
  [tapped release];

 -(void)imageSelected
  {
    NSLog(@"Selected an Image");
  }
```

Comment: I just tried this and it isn't even registering I touched the image. I was thinking back to it, and my proof of concept I finished before I updated to the new xcode, still running on iOS 4. Now the proof of concept isn't even working. Could it be an issue with iOS 5?

Comment: It's possible, I would create a new project to try out your POC and see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you create a new project with Xcode 4.2 and iOS5? If that's the case it might be that you are retaining/releasing objects and iOS5 now has ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)

Comment: I did create a new project, and when I declare my image view in the .h file: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView; Aside from that, there isn't any retain or release used.

Comment: Ok, so creating a button the exact same way as I did with the image, and applying your method here that you suggested to the button, it works just fine. But not for the ImageView.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to set userInteractionEnabled to YES in your viewDidLoad method like below:

```
[myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Note that for the myImageView, checking User Interaction Enabled via Identity Inspector didn't work for me.

Then change

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

to

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
```

so that the touchesBegan method looks like below:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == myImageView) {
       // place any code here when myImageView is touched
    }
 }
```