# Subview Blocking Parent View TouchesBegan?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a view that has a `UITableView` as a `subview`, and it completely covers the parent view. When I try to implement `touchesBegan` for the parent view, I'm noticing the method isn't being called at all. Is there anyway to override this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `touchesBegan` method has to do with the frame of the parent view. If the frame isn't visible for the parent view and is totally enclosed by the `subviews`, the parent view won't receive touches.

Answer (score 13):

Actually there is a way to override this behavior. You need to extend each child object that are blocking the parent view and override `touchesBegan` method like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
   [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

For example, if you have a UIButton inside a UIScrollView which is inside a UIView then you need to create two custom classes. One extending UIButton and other extending UIScrollView. In each of these custom classes you need to add the above method definition. After these changes you will be able to receive `touchesBegan` event in parent UIView.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set:

```
[theViewThatIsCoveringParent setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

This way all touches will be caught by the parent.

Comment: This did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do this: [Why isn't my UIViewController in the responder chain for its view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390986/why-isnt-my-uiviewcontroller-in-the-responder-chain-for-its-view/11921597#11921597)

In short:

- Link your views to your controller.
- Add a property called `nextResponderPlusSomething` (there is already a `nextResponder`) inside the view which is getting touches
- In `viewdidload` set this property to the controller (self)
- Inside the `touchesBegan` add a call to the `nextResponderPlusSomething:touchesBegan`
- Implement this event on controller, sending the event to the view that you want to be called.